# How can I listen to database table rows (if inserted/updated/deleted) and display them in datatable using spring boot?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc, datatables

I've a requirement where the HTML page having a datatable which will display records from one particular database table. And the respective datatable should listen to the same table for any rows which are getting inserted/updated/deleted using spring boot.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`@Entity @EntityListeners(CustomizedListener.class) public class MyEntity {}`

```
@Transactional
public void saveOperation(long entityId) {
    repository.findById(entityId)
        .ifPresent(entity -> {
            entity.domainOperation();
            repository.save(entity);
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new DomainEvent());
        });
}`public class CustomizedListener {
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuditTrailListener.class);

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
@PreRemove
private void beforeAnyUpdateIntheDatabse(User user) {
    if (user.getId() == 0) {
        log.info("About to add a user");
    } else {
        log.info("About to update/delete user: " + user.getId());
    }
    }

@PostPersist
@PostUpdate
@PostRemove
private void afterAnyUpdateInTheDataBase(User user) {
    log.info("add or update or delete complete for user: " + user.getId());
}

@PostLoad
private void afterLoadInTheDatabase(User user) {
    log.info(" user loaded from database: " + user.getId());
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Santhosh. How can I send these entities to existing datatable in view please.

Comment: 1. inside service layer, you can convert  convert entities to DTO , please check this link .. how to convert entity to DTO , https://www.amitph.com/spring-entity-to-dto/.

Comment: return these DTO's to UI .

Answer (score 0):

JPA specifies seven optional lifecycle events that are called:

---

- before persist is called for a new entity – **@PrePersist**
- after persist is called for a new entity – **@PostPersist**
- before an entity is removed – **@PreRemove**
- after an entity has been deleted – **@PostRemove**
- before the update operation – **@PreUpdate**
- after an entity is updated – **@PostUpdate**
- after an entity has been loaded – **@PostLoad**

---

A code example in Spring Boot:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

private String type:

....... some code here ...

@PrePersist
private void prePersistFunction(){

    log.info("PrePersist method called");

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(type)){
        type = "STANDARD_CUSTOMER";
    }
}


@PreUpdate
public void preUpdateFunction(){
log.info("PreUpdate method called");
}
}
```

---

***Just take a look at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events).***

Comment: Thanks @Amir. How can I send these entities to existing datatable in view please.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what you mean by view? they are Hibernate annotations, so you should use them in your Entity class. 
You can apply any operation to the entity, for example, in @PreUpdate.

The Hibernate handles everything for you, use these annotations in your entity and perform your logic in the method (like 'preUpdateFunction' in the example above).

Please feel free to ask any question <3

Comment: These annotations and methods must be in your entity class, just config your application.properties (or .YAML), to connect to your DB, and create a Repository and a Service. if you want more help add that here, you can find these things with googleing.

Answer (score -1):

Your client (HTML page) should be sending continous requests to server in order to get the latest data from the server.

Comment: any template or example you can share please?